# Angular multiple filtering Observable, rxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, filtering

Hello i want use 3x filter input `(1x input:text, 2x select)`. I have a Observable list `userList$: Observable<User[]>`. In `ngOnInit()` i filter this list use my `input:text`.

```
userList$: Observable<User[]>
inputControl = new FormControl();  // input type text
selectStatus = new FormControl();  // select
filteredData$:any;

ngOnInit(){
   this.filteredData$ = combineLatest(
      this.userList$,
      this.inputControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(""),
        debounceTime(400)
      )
    ).pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      filter(([list, input]) => Boolean(list)),
      map(([list, input]) => {
        return list.filter(
          ({login}) => !input || login.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) !== -1);
      })
    );  
    this.userList$ = this.filteredData$;
}
```

When i add one more filter first filter not working.. Code when i use 2x filtered:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.filteredData$ = combineLatest(
      this.userList$,
      this.inputControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(""),
        debounceTime(400)
      )
    ).pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      filter(([list, input]) => Boolean(list)),
      map(([list, input]) => {
        return list.filter(
          ({login}) => !input || login.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) !== -1);
      })
    );  
    this.filteredData$ = combineLatest(
      this.userList$,
      this.selectStatus.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(""),
        debounceTime(400)
      )
    ).pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      filter(([list, input]) => Boolean(list)),
      map(([list, input]) => {
        if(input == 1){
          return list.filter(
            ({is_banned, is_deleted}) =>  is_banned !== 1 || is_deleted !== 1);
        }else if (input == 2){
          return list.filter(({is_banned}) => is_banned == 1 );
        }else{
          return list.filter(({is_deleted}) => is_deleted == 1 );
        }
      })
    );
    this.userList$ = this.filteredData$;
 }
```

How can i filtering this list when use 3x filter field?

Comment: You keep re-assiging the list everytime. What you want is to do all 3 filter actions in a single map. So combine all you filters together with your list.

Comment: I must add 2 more combine latest to 1 function and observe 3 input in 1 function? I can't add more filter to last map because my input get me value from 1 input.

Comment: @MikeOne can u show me how can i include 3x input filter?

Comment: Are you trying to filter user list based on input and selected status ? you can combine userList, input & select in single combineLatest which will help you filter list. 

Also, I am not sure why you have this.userList$ = this.filteredData$; ?

Comment: I have this.userList$ = this.filteredData$ because i need refresh view. Can u show me example code how can i combine 2x input field in one combineLatest?

Comment: I do this.. Very thanks for help bro!